# Install mobile partner using super user

Tags: sudo, su

I am trying to install mobile partner of Huawei Technologies. The manual asks me to run the install file using super user command. As I type the su command, it asks password.
I don't know the password for the super user(root), so I tried sudo command. But it says that, 
"Install NDIS driver failed.
The compiling environment is not all ready.
Please check gcc, make and kernel build(/lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/build) to be all installed?"

Then the terminal asks me to press a key to finish other installations.
"NDIS is disabled and only modem can be used"

Please help me.

Comment: This is a very bad idea to install Mobile Partner. It has lot's of issues on Ubuntu and also disables sudo password. That is a security issue. You do not need this crap.

Comment: What should I use then? I need to use wireless internet on my pc.

Answer (score 1):

You may need `gcc` which allows you to compile code.

`sudo apt-get install gcc` should help. `sudo apt-get install build-essential` might also be required. I'll admit I'm no expert with this! but the error suggests missing packages.

Comment: I used both your suggested commands. gcc is already at its newest version but for build essentials, the compiler gave error: "E: unable to locate package build" and "E: unable to locate package essentials"

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/build-essential - `sudo apt-get install build-essential` should be enough as gcc is a dependency.  note the hyphen